# Implement an equalizer like the Foobar's SuperEQ in CSCore

Tags: c#, c++, audio, cscore

I was wondering if is possible to implement an equalizer with the same algorithms as the [SuperEQ](http://www.foobar2000.org/equalizer), the equalizer of Foobar player. I know that CSCore have a great equalizer, but it is based into a simpler parametric equalizer.

In Foobar, if I simply remove 10 dB of each band, then the "total" sound will have 10 dB less volume and no alteration in equalizations.

It is hard (if not impossible) to do the same with CSCore. Given a 10 band equalizer, if I remove 10 dB on each band, then the total sound will be different from the unequalized one, and not only with less volume.

There is anyway to use the SuperEQ library in CSCore? If not, there's another way to archive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could translate to code to c#, vb.net,... implement the ISampleSource or IWaveSource interface and make the algorithm work.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to make this. But the code of supereq seems crazy. I was hopping for a solution with some p/invoke.

Comment: Of course if it's a C-Dll you can also use p/invoke.